# any others like iframe in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iframe, frame

I am using asp.net 3.5. I want to show a page(with a link) in my aspx page. Firstly, I tried to use iframe or frame. However, if the frame is not supported, my page can not be shown. Is there any other way, or any controls for that goal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try a google search for "screen scraping" in ASP.NET. You'd basically open a connection to the site and copy HTML to your site.

This could get messy depending on what you're trying to pull into your site.